# If input is not the specific type, print.. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to add an "if" statement to my code. If "guess" is not an integer, print ("You did not enter a number, please re-enter") and then repeat the code from the input area instead of the starting point. The following is my attempt, however when I enter a non-int at guess input, `ValueError` appears. Thanks in advance!

```
#This is a guess the number game.
import random
print ("Hello, what is your name?")
name = input()

print ("Well, " + name + " I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20, please take a guess.")
secretNumber = random.randint(1,20)

#Establish that they get 6 tries without specifically telling them
for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    guess = int(input())
    if type(guess) != int:
        print ("You did not enter a number, please re-enter")
        continue


    if guess < secretNumber:
        print ("The number you guessed was too low")
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print ("The number you guessed was too high")
    else:
        break

if guess == secretNumber:
    print ("Oh yeah, you got it")
else:
    print ("Bad luck, try again next time, the number I am thinking is " + str(secretNumber))

print ("You took " + str(guessesTaken) + " guesses.")
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how your code "failed".

Comment: `guess = int(input())`, then `if type(guess) != int`. Eh?

Comment: Not beautiful but how about `if type(guess) == type(5)`?

Comment: If `guess = int(input())` succeeds, then `type(guess)` will be `int`, so the following `if type(guess) != int` will never be True. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: Error that occurred is when entering non-int to "guess".

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers

Answer (score 1):

Use a `try` and `except`:

```
for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    try:
        guess = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        print ("You did not enter a number, please re-enter")
        continue
```

So you try to convert the input into an integer. If this does not work, Python will throw an `ValueError`. You catch this error and ask the user try again.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This no longer returns an error however, when continue executes, it still only allows 6 tries (guessesTaken?

Comment: Yes, the loop is finished after six tries with a wrong input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple while loop that waits until the user has entered a digit. For example,

```
guess = input("Enter a number: ") # type(guess) gives "str"

while(not guess.isdigit()):  # Checks if the string is not a numeric digit
    guess = input("You did not enter a number. Please re-enter: ")
```

That way, if the string they entered is not a digit, they will receive a prompt as many times as necessary until they enter an integer (as a string, of course).

You can then convert the digit to an integer as before:

```
guess = int(guess)
```

For example, consider the following cases:

```
"a string".isdigit() # returns False
"3.14159".isdigit() # returns False
"3".isdigit() # returns True, can use int("3") to get 3 as an integer
```